# Export mysql data as CSV in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

In my code, I need to preserve all commas in each fields from the mysql table in CSV Export...

For this I used the double quotes to all fields. This code is perfectly running in the Linux System.. While running the same code in windows, double quotes also displaying in Exported CSV file.. What is the problem in this? can anyone tell me why it is happening like this?

```
    function  arrayToCSV($array, $header_row = true, $col_sep = ",", $row_sep = "\n", $qut = '"',$pgeTyp ="")
    {
    /*col_sep =htmlentities($col_sep);
    $row_sep =htmlentities($row_sep);
    $qut =htmlentities($qut);*/
    if (!is_array($array) or !is_array($array[0])) return false;
    //Header row.
    if ($header_row)
    {
    foreach ($array[0] as $key => $val)
    {
    //Escaping quotes.
    $key = str_replace($qut, "$qut$qut", $key);
    $output .= $col_sep.$qut.$key.$qut;
    }
    $output = substr($output, 1)."\n".$row_sep;
    }
    //Data rows.
    foreach ($array as $key => $val)
    {
    $tmp = '';

    foreach ($val as $cell_key => $cell_val)
    {  
    if($pgeTyp!="twitter" && $pagTyp!="jigsaw" && $pgeTyp=="")
    $timeValue = @checkTimeStamp($cell_val);
    else  $timeValue = '';
    if($timeValue=="True")
    {
    $cell_val = str_replace($qut, "$qut$qut", convert_time_zone($cell_val,'d-M-y h:i:s'));
    }
    else
    {
    $cell_val = str_replace($qut, "$qut$qut", $cell_val);
    }

    $tmp .= $col_sep.$qut.$cell_val.$qut;
    }
    $output .= substr($tmp, 1).$row_sep;
    }
    return $output;
    }
```

Function call is,

```
$dbResult1[] =array('url_twitter_userid' => $selecttwittermainFtch['url_twitter_userid'],'url_tweet_name' => "$url_tweet_name",'url_twitter_uname' => "$url_twitter_uname",'url_twitter_url' => $selecttwittermainFtch['url_twitter_url'],'url_twitter_location' => "$url_twitter_location",'url_twitter_followers' => $selecttwittermainFtch['url_twitter_followers'],'url_twitter_following' => $selecttwittermainFtch['url_twitter_following'],'url_modified_on' => $modifiedon);   
echo arrayToCSV($dbResult1, true, ", ", "\n",  '','twitter');
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Could you please post youe php code?

Comment: Use same editor to view your file. You are adding quotes so it will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sqlQueryToCSV($filename, $query)
{
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $headers = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
            $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
    }
    $fp = fopen(mysql_real_escape_string(getcwd().'\\'.$filename), 'w');
    if ($fp) {
 fputcsv($fp, $headers);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $arrayValues = array();
     foreach ($headers as $header)
     {
         $arrayValues[] = $row[$header];
     }
     fputcsv($fp, $arrayValues);
 }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Source: http://forums.exchangecore.com/topic/907-function-to-convert-mysql-query-to-csv-file-with-php/

Comment: this is applicable for the export of values from a file.but i need to export directly from mysql database not from file

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening it in Windows with whatever program (Guessing Excel), you should be able to specify what characters you use to delimit/surround the fields. It's probably just assuming that you are just wanting to use commas to separate but ignoring the double quotes surrounding them.

Comment: If I remove this Double quotes then for each commas in a field , it splits the data into next cell.. How can I avoid this cell splitting